# how to know if a form_alter is being invoked through an ajax request?

Tags: ajax, forms

I am altering a node add form using hook_id_form_alter and inside that i am doing a drupal_goto, if query parameter is missing a mandatory token value. Now, in the add node form, there is an image field. When i'm trying to upload that image, which is an ajax request without the token, the form_alter function is invoked and hence fails.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show us the code that you tried!

Comment: use `drupal_set_message('whatever');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely an AHAH issue. See [Adding dynamic form elements using AHAH](http://drupal.org/node/331941). The form is loaded from the cache and then the form alter is called irrespective of whether it is full post request or via Ajax. You might want to change the logic in a way to save the result of checking the token the first time the form_alter is called in a $_SESSION variable (Save the token in the session variable). And change the logic to include an additional check for the presence of the same $_SESSION variable if there is no token value, and if present if that token is valid (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect ajax request with this code...

```
   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])&& strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])=='xmlhttprequest'){
     // logic
   }
```

then setup variable with :

```
    drupal_add_js(array('myVar' => TRUE), 'setting');
```

This will be available in your js code as:

```
    Drupal.settings.myVar
```

So you can check if your variable is set before ajax callback will execute your code

```
  if(Drupal.settings.myVar == true) {
      return true;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**: For anyone still trying to figure out how to check whether `hook_form_alter` is being called by an AJAX request (like file uploader), you can use this:

```php
$ajax = isset($form_state['input']['ajax_page_state']) && !empty($form_state['input']['ajax_page_state']);
if (!$ajax) {
  // ..anything that should not be called for AJAX should go here..
}
```